# How to change time in available line in python

Tags: python, time, python-datetime

Let's assume there is a code which is using with anaconda prompt. While the program flowing, every second is printing to screen. However, here every second is printed the same or next line. 
I want to print every second in the same place.
For example, print 30 and after 1 second later, delete 30 and print 29 to the same place.

How can I do that with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\r` to return to the start of line instead of moving the cursor to the next line (`\n`). Whether or not this works with your shell is an open question; e.g. IDLE occasionally has problems with this.

```
import time
for x in range(10):
    print(x, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
print()  # to add a newline, finally
print('The end!')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! \r is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

After every second when you have to clear the screen you can use this :

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

Comment: Thank you!. It actually affects my other systems.

Comment: Does that mean it does not help in your case?

Comment: Yes, the below answer solved the problem. I used " \r". Thank you so much took the time.